# How to get the particular cell value from a gridview and to display it in a textbox using jquery in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui, c#-4.0

The following is my grid view code. In this, I have one column "Syllabus". In the next column I'm having edit and delete buttons. On clicking the Edit button, a popup will display. I displayed that popup using jquery. In the popup, I'm having a textbox for Syllabus. But I dont know how to get that syllabus value from the gridview column and to display its value in the popup for editing its value?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gdvwSyllabus" CssClass="enquiryTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText ="Syllabus" DataField ="Syllabus" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <ul class="enquiryList1">
                           <li><a href="#"><asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/edit2.png" runat="server" ID="btnSyllabusEdit" CssClass="btnEdit" /></a></li>
                           <li><a><asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/delete2.png" runat="server" ID="btnDelete" /></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

This is my popup code which I designed it as a table.This table will popup on clicking the edit button.I want to display the "syllabus" value in the "txtsyllabus" textbox for edit.

```
 <table style="border: 0px; margin-left: 15px;" border="0" align="left">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Syllabus <span class="ErrorField">*</span>:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtsyllabus" CssClass="txtbox txtSyllabus" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td align="left">
                         <a href="#"><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Save" CssClass="btnStyle btnSyllabusSubmit" runat="server" /></a>
                      </td>
                 </tr>
            </table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean to get the particular row selected? or a given cell in that row?

Comment: Yeah to get the particular row selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling a javascript function from button on client click as following:

```
function showpopup(details)
{
document.getElementById('texbox').value=details
document.getElementById('divpopup').style.display='block'
```

return false;
    }

on gridview item databound event do the code like this

```
btn=e.item.findcontrol("editbouttn")
btn.attributes.add("onclick","return showpopup(" & e.item.dataitem("details") & ");"
```

please let me know if this does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ravi. As I'm a fresher, could you please explain me in detail? I displayed the popup using jquery on clicking the edit button. But how to select that particular column for displaying the popup and to display that corresponding values in it?